# Is it possible to request password from a POST request?

Tags: http, post, libcurl, basic-authentication

The client does not know whether to submit username and password before a POST request is issued.
So it tries to send a POST request. Then the server requires a basic authentication.
The client then ask the user for username and password.

Is it possible to resubmit a POST request after asking for username and password?

How to write the code in libcurl?

Does it double the traffic of the resubmission, because a POST request can be very large?

Comment: The client will have to resubmit the request, including the payload as the first will be rejected. There is no way around that without changing the service accepting the request.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP 1.1 way of fixing the problem of the double data send is the "Expect: 100-continue" header that libcurl will include by itself. It allows a server to reject the POST before any data is sent.

In reality however, most servers don't implement that (properly) so you'll then do the double post.